# How to migrate old models to new models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I decided to rebuild an established app from scratch. Now, I need to migrate all the old data to the new schema.

Most of the tables match up, but there are some differences that keep me from just porting the data directly over.

So how would I go about transferring the old data to the new schema?

It's not only renaming table names...there's also some data changes that need to happen along with it. So, something like basically creating new entires in the new database using the old database as the "base" data for creating the records.

Comment: You could generate seed files from the database and then rename columns/tables as needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393246/create-seed-file-from-data-already-in-the-database

Answer (score 0):

You could use views that mimmic the existing base table names so those queries don't break and work in the new database design a section at a time. Eventually your queries and procedures would eliminate the use of the views that mimmic the old database.