# Easiest way to dump Heroku database for use in local seed.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, seeding, database-dump

I can dump a heroku database with `$ heroku pgbackups:capture`. Also, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393246/create-seed-file-from-data-already-in-the-database) shows that there are tools for taking a *development* database and dumping it to seed.rb.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to combine the two processes, effectively dumping the data from a production Heroku database into my local seeds.rb for more realistic development testing.

If this is possible, what's the cleanest way to do this?

**Update:**

Based on the insightful answer from dB', I may consider using PGSQL locally. I am still interested, however, in the seed.rb aspect of the question if there is a way to do that easily.

Comment: [This gem](https://github.com/zenprogrammer/seed_dump) looks like it will do what you want handily.  If you don't *need* to use Rails to load your data, you might also consider just writing rake tasks to dump/load the database (seeds.rb could even run them).  If you have a substantial amount of data this will be *a lot* faster, and avoid things like observer hooks (e.g. say creating users sends an email).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways to accomplish such a thing. @dB' has outlined one of them - using [the PG Backups add-on to export your database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export). It's a great options but involves a few (trivial) manual commands.

I would recommend using the [pg:transfer Heroku CLI plugin](http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/pgtransfer-is-the-new-taps/) to transfer the data in a single step. Under the covers it's still very much the same thing happening as with using PG Backups, but it's packaged a bit nicer and has some useful defaults.

From your app's directory, copy your production database locally (assuming a local PG db), by installing the plugin and execute the `pg:transfer` command.

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer
$ heroku pg:transfer
```

There are a couple options you can set as well. See [my writeup](http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/pgtransfer-is-the-new-taps/) for more details.

Hope that helps! And yes, please do use the [same database during development as you do in production](http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity).

Comment: Outbound links are requesting browser installs.

Comment: This project is deprecated and is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but have you tried copying the database to your local machine using pgbackups:capture and pg_restore?  This approach doesn't use seeds.rb, but still recreates your production database on your local machine.  It looks something like this.

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```

(This code is copied liberally from [the explanation at the Heroku dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).)

Comment: Will this work if the local DB is non-PostgreSQL (e.g. SQLite)?

Comment: No, it won't.  (Though being able to do this is one of many good reasons to switch over to PGSQL on your dev machine.)