# How do I create a seed file based on my development database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4.2, seeding

I want to assemble the data and settings of a Rails application offline and then push it to production. The ideal scenario is if I set up the application state offline locally and then have that exact same data and application code state in the server in production.

Is there a way to automatically generate a seed file based on the data in the current development database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of gems that will probably provide what you're looking for e.g. seed_dump, https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump. Also this question may help - [Create seed file from data already in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393246/create-seed-file-from-data-already-in-the-database)