# Rails: upload local database to remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails App, I scraped many data from other websites, and it's all on my local `development database`. 
Now, I want to deploy my website to `Heroku`, and I want to upload the local data as well, so I don't need to scrape those data again. How can I do it?

I think I can just convert the local data(just a few models) into `yml`, or `csv`, and then write a `rake task` to read from those file.

I'm wondering if there are better approaches.

Comment: Have you tried `pg:push` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push ?

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11356344/2150422

Comment: @cqcn1991 Please do consider accepting the answer if it has helped you in solving your question .

Comment: @GhostBuster I'm about to, but now I'm struggling with other code problem, I'll accept once I test that gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [this](https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db)

Allows you to take backup of your db using simple commands and then you just need to restore it on the live database . Quite easy .